# Allowing TABs in Char Validator

Tags: python-2.7, validation, wxpython

Currently I have a data input screen where the user has to navigate between input fields using the mouse. I would like to add a TAB facility so that they can TAB between input fields, e.g. Last Name → First Name → DOB, etc. The input screen makes use of Validators to prevent users inputting nonsense:-

```
def OnChar(self, evt):
    key = chr(evt.GetKeyCode())
    if ord(key) in [wx.WXK_BACK, wx.WXK_DELETE]:
        evt.Skip()
    if self.flag  == LETTERS and key not in string.letters:
        return
    if self.flag  == DECIMAL_DIGITS and key not in string.digits:
        return
    if self.flag  == HEX_DIGITS and key not in string.hexdigits:
        return
    if self.flag  == ALPHA_NUMERIC and key not in string.printable:
        return
    evt.Skip()
```

I have added:-

```
style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL | wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE
```

to the Frame. However the Validator traps the TABs. Is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: It doesn't look like anyone understands the question, perhaps a better explanation of what you are aiming for might help.

Comment: Revised first paragraph for better clarity

Comment: Doesn't `if ord(key) == wx.WXK_TAB: return` before your other `if` statements do what you want?

Comment: No, the TAB key is just ignored. Sorry for delay - been ill with RSV!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are converting the key to `chr()` it is not recognising `wx.WXK_TAB` see the following to demonstrate your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx
class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "Tab Key Test",size=(310,120))
        self.Stop_prog = False
        self.top = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.text_input = wx.TextCtrl(self.top, wx.ID_ANY, size=(300,25))
        self.sizer.Add(self.text_input)
        self.text_input.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKey)
        self.top.Sizer = self.sizer
        self.top.Sizer.Fit(self.top)
        self.Show()

    def OnKey(self,event):
        print "Key Pressed", event.GetKeyCode()
        keycode = event.GetKeyCode()
        try:
            charkey = chr(event.GetKeyCode())
            print "Character Key", charkey
        except:
            print "unable to convert key to a character in the range 256"
        if keycode == wx.WXK_F1: 
            self.Close()
        elif keycode == wx.WXK_TAB:
            print "TAB"
            self.text_input.SetValue("You pressed Tab")
        else:
            event.Skip()

def main():
    ex = wx.App()
    Example(None)
    ex.MainLoop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```